# SpriteKit loading new scene but sprite immediately drops

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm following this (https://www.raywenderlich.com/100560/video-tutorial-how-to-make-a-game-like-flappy-bird-in-swift-part-6-collision-detection) video tutorial series to understand SpriteKit, however using Xcode 7.2 there seems to be a bug where, after the sprite falls, the user taps on the screen and switchToNewGame is called, however the sprite immediately drops to the ground and I can't figure out why.  Below is switchToNewGame and entire code in this gist:  https://gist.github.com/gesabo/2e585f22c2860af13e099590a2e00e47

```
 func switchToNewGame() {
        runAction(popAction)
        let newScene = GameScene(size: size)
        let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithColor(SKColor.blackColor(), duration: 1.0)
        view?.presentScene(newScene, transition: transition)
    }
```

I thought maybe it was related to this line `physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)` in `didMoveToView` which RW uses because he said he wants to control gravity rather than SpriteKit, but removing it didn't seem to effect this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't he fall?, your default GameState is .Play, so as soon as your scene loads, your bird starts to fall.  Now when you are transitioning, your scene is running, so your bird may be further down due to this.

I would recommend

1) Changing the gameState to something other than play,  then changing it to play when you are ready

2) pause the scene during transitions,  look at SKTransition documentation to achieve your desired effect

3) use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) to load your new scene, so that loading time does not affect scene time.  (Basically the first update time you get from scene could be a large time, distorting transitions)

Note: as of 9.3, the paused variable is bugged,  for some reason it changes the pause state of all children as well, so when transitioning,  you may get some undesired effects

Comment: Thanks for your answer however (1) trying different game states didn't seem to help, however I'm not really sure what lifecycle method would be appropriate for setting to `.Play`? I tried in didMoveToView but same result (2) pausing incoming scene is set to true by default so wasn't able to find any help there (3) good thought but loading the new scene on the main queue = same result.

Comment: There is a bug with sprite kit and pause, so you may think the scene is paused, but it may not be

Comment: I would suggest setting the gamestate to play on didmovetoview,  I am pretty sure this gets called when the transition is done

Comment: Thanks, that's what I tried but same result, I also set pauseIncomingScene to true but same.

Comment: in your did move to view function, at the end,  pause the scene, see what result you get.

Comment: it was paused, so I added this line `newScene.paused = true` in SwitchToNewGame I get the desired behavior.  Thank you!!  want to add to your answer and I'll mark as correct?

Comment: it must not have been...setting true to pauseIncomingScene on the transition did not work, however setting it to true on the new scene did

Comment: pause is weird, because it sets the pause on all of the children as well,  which is wrong. I had to actually make this complex pause override method to handle this bug,  hopefully apple fixes it in the future